# Add data from a server using an API on a marker window

Tags: android-maps-v2

I'm coding an Android App and I want to display markers using the Google Maps API. Those markers have a window where I want to display live data from my server (by using an api request). Is it possible to do it ?

Thanks for your help.

Luc